# preg_replace html ascii

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove HTML Ascii codes, how do I go about removing something like: `&#039;`

I tried `'/&#[a-zA-Z0-9\s];/'` but it didn't work.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Why are you including whitespace and alpha characters in the character class?

Comment: @Phil I have no idea, maybe I should remove that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be `'/&#[a-zA-Z0-9]+?;/'` if that's what you want to do. I added a plus sign which means one or more of the preceding identifiers.

Comment: I guess this is one of those *we've all been there* moments. Thanks!

Comment: Might want to make that match non-greedy, ie `+?`

Comment: @Phil - I read someone about this non-greedy `?`, what's it mean exactly?

Comment: @Brogrammer, It means that it matches as few of the preceding token as possible before satisfying the next. See here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ . Great site to text Regex

Comment: @Brogrammer without it, that expression could match `&#039; hi there brogrammer;`. Making it non-greedy stops at the first semi-colon though if you changed the character class to numeric only (`\d`) you'd avoid this same problem

Comment: Yeah I did change it to Numeric, but I guess I'll put the `?` in anyway as it seems to be best practice.

Comment: I'd actually change the expression to `&#(\d+|x[0-9A-Fa-f]+);`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references